# How to use my Windows folder in Mobaxterm power shell?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c, mobaxterm

I have multiples tcp programming c codes on my desktop and I want to test them. I have downloaded Mobaxterm, it works great but I don't know how to get access to my desktop.

Comment: Hi, have you tried `/drives/c` in MobaXterm? Local drives are suposed to reside in `/drives/`. Also I know it should be a panel in the app, that let's you transfer files.

Comment: I didn't find such directory in the shell

Comment: What directory are you in when you start MobaXterm? I believe the default is /home/mobaxterm/, in which case, you would just cd Desktop

Comment: This is a horrible question.  Can I assume that OP is using WSL?  You don't tell us enough to even come close to answering this question.